# Node.js express delete href routing doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, handlebars.js

i have some problem with my delete route. It cant get the /delete/{{id}} route from index.js

i have already read express documentation and i have to write the code same with the documentation, and it still didn't work

input.hbs

```
<main>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Hasil Input</h1>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nama</th>
                        <th>NIM</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {{#each data}}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{name}}</td>
                        <td>{{nim}}</td>
                        <td> 
                            <a href="delete/{{key}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>  
                        </td>  
                    </tr>
                    {{/each}}                       
                </tbody>
            </table>            
        </div>
    </main>
```

index.js

```
app.post('/delete/(:id)', (req,res,next) => {
    id = req.params.id; 
    ref = database.ref('Person/'+id );
    ref.remove()
    res.redirect('/input')
})
```

it still show message like this

```
Cannot GET /delete/-LbdQOw7xbv_Vrp0OD-u
```

Comment: The GET part of that message is the clue. Clicking an anchor element will cause the browser to navigate to the specified href which is a GET request not a POST which is what you set it as, `app.post(...)`

Comment: even though i don't use the parentheses around my route parameter, it still same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delete method to do that,
here is a simple example.

Let's suppose there's a Member class.

In the server side:

```
    router.delete('url/:id',(req,res) => {
        const found = members.some(member => member.id === parseInt(req.params.id));

    if(found){
      // Do something
      res.json( { msg: "member deleted",members: members.filter( member => member.id !== parseInt(req.params.id))});
    }
else{
          res.status(400).json( { msg: `No member with the id of ${req.params.id}`})
        }

      });
```

And in the client side,
you can use Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url/id',
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```